# $X_n \to X$ almost surely and $Y_n-X_n \to 0$ in probability implies $Y_n \to X$ in probability?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space where the r.v. $X$, and sequences $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are defined. If $X_n\rightarrow X\space a.s.$ and $Y_n-X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability, then show that $Y_n\rightarrow X$ in probability?

So we need to show that $\forall\epsilon>0\space\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(|Y_n-X|\geq\epsilon)=0$, given that $\mathbb{P}(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n=X)=1$ and $\forall\delta>0,\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n-Y_n|\geq\delta)=0$

If this were just the pointwise case then its quite trivial as the triangle-inequality will give the result, but I am not sure why to translate this to show convergence in probability, which I am guessing is pretty straight forward ans uses the limit superior and inferior of sets but I am not sure how to go about it, so any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that $$\mathbb{P}(|X-Y_n| \geq 2\epsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X-X_n| \geq \epsilon) + \mathbb{P}(|Y_n-X_n| \geq \epsilon)$$ and the fact that almost surely convergence implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Thanks, how did you get that inequality? is it because of the triangle inequality, so $\{|Y_n-X|\geq 2\epsilon\}\subset\{|Y_n-X_n|\geq\epsilon\}\cup\{|X_n-Y|\geq\epsilon\}$. I can "see" why this subset relation should be true but can't see how to show it rigorously, as triangle inequality implies that $\{|Y_n-X_n|+|X_n-Y|\geq 2\epsilon\}$. So not quite sure how to break it up as a union?

Comment: @user152874 Yes, it follows from the triangle inequality. If $\omega \in \{|Y_n-X| \geq 2\epsilon\}$, then by the triangle inequality $$\begin{align*} 2 \epsilon \leq |Y_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| &\leq |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| + |X_n(\omega)-Y_n(\omega)| \\ &\leq 2 \max\{|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|,|Y_n(\omega)-X_n(\omega)|\}. \end{align*}$$ Hence, $$\max\{|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|,|Y_n(\omega)-X_n(\omega)|\} \geq \epsilon, $$ and this means that $$\omega \in \{|X-X_n| \geq \epsilon\} \cup \{|Y_n-X_n| \geq \epsilon\}.$$

Comment: @Byron Schmuland Thanks for correcting the typo. :)

Comment: @user152874 You are welcome.