# If $X_n\rightarrow^{p}\mu_{n}$ and $\mu_{n}\rightarrow\mu$, does $X_n\rightarrow^{p}\mu$ as well?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

This seems trivial but I just want to be careful about it. By definition, I would like $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|X_n-\mu|>\epsilon)=0$ for $\epsilon>0$. But can I just rewrite it as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|X_n-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu_n|>\epsilon)=0$ and bring the limit out from there? That seems really odd to me.

Comment: I think the question below helps:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175926/x-n-to-x-almost-surely-and-y-n-x-n-to-0-in-probability-implies-y-n-to-x?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by $X_n \to \mu_n$? A sequence of random variables may converge to a random variable, but $\mu_n$ appears to be a sequence (not a random variable).

Comment: $|X_n-\mu| >\epsilon$ implies that either $|X_n-\mu_n| >\epsilon /2$ or $|\mu_n-\mu| >\epsilon /2$.

Comment: Sorry for missing info, I derived $S_n/n \rightarrow^{p} \mu_n$ from WLLN for the question I'm working with. So I think it's a sequence.

Comment: You should say $X_n-\mu_n \stackrel{P}\to 0$ for the question to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with writing
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n-\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n|>\epsilon)=0$$
which is that the $n$ in the outer limit and the $n$ in the inner limit are two different dummy variables. Each is only defined with the confines of its own limit. But because one limit is inside the other the $n$ in $\mu_n$ is ambiguous. Is it the $n$ of the inner limit, or of the outer limit? In this case, it isn't hard to figure out, but you shouldn't have to figure it out.

The correct usage is to have different variable names: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n-\lim_{m\to\infty}\mu_m|>\epsilon)=0$$

I'm sure that spoils your next step, which I guess would have been to say
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|X_n-\mu_n|>\epsilon)=0$$

But this is something you need to justify in a more rigorous fashion.